# How many eggs can one eat per day?

Tags: nutrition

I've read conflicting information on how many eggs one can eat per day:

[Daily Health Post - How Many Eggs a Day Can You Safely Eat?](http://dailyhealthpost.com/how-many-eggs-a-day-can-you-safely-eat/2/)

> How many eggs a day can you safely eat? Apparently, as many as you want, if you pay attention to your total calorie intake and are careful about carbohydrate intake. If you have diabetes, you can safely eat eggs too, but will need to be particularly attentive to carbohydrates and blood sugar control.

[Men's Fitness - Am I Eating Too Many Eggs?](http://www.mensfitness.com/nutrition/what-to-eat/eating-too-many-eggs)

> A 2008 report from the Physicians Health Study backs up Smith’s suggestion, finding that eating one egg per day is generally safe—but that more than that can increase your heart disease risk later in life. (Note that we’re talking about yolks here. You can have unlimited whites.)

---

More details:

- The individual is healthy, BMI of 20, has no major medical condition, and regarding sports activities walks 30 minutes per day.
- Eggs are large chicken eggs (50 grams)
- I am looking for an approximate upper bound on the number of eggs one can eat per day on average while staying healthy in the long run

Comment: Note that of the digestible portion of the egg, the white is mostly protein, according to [a Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=egg+white). According to [another Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=egg+yolk), the yolks are high in fat, including saturated fat, and very high in cholesterol. In other words, the limit really concerns how many egg _yolks_ you can safely eat in a day, as the whites have very little to be worried about. Finally, due diligence reveals that Google pulls its nutrition information from the USDA (see 'sources' at the bottom of the nutrition info).

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist - More and more, the cholesterol in egg yolks being bad is being proven a myth for healthy individuals (The constraints in the original question). They may actually be beneficial, as cholesterol and saturated fat helps in testosterone production. Much of the "bad" association may have been mistakenly attributed to eggs, and ignoring the usual side dishes of bacon and sausage.

Comment: @JohnP Personally, I consume ridiculous quantities of eggs, and I don't disagree with you. For validity's sake, however, care to provide references? Note that I didn't deny that some cholesterol is good for you, but [the liver produces all the cholesterol you need, and even more in those with diets high in saturated fats](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/Conditions/Cholesterol/AboutCholesterol/About-Cholesterol_UCM_001220_Article.jsp#mainContent). The same source also discusses how excess cholesterol can cause cardiovascular problems, including heart attack and stroke, among a number of others.

Comment: @DaveL What do you want me to narrow down?

Comment: @DaveL Sure, added. Is it okay now?

Comment: Ignoring the health aspect, apparently it is possible to eat [141 eggs in 8 minutes](http://www.wdrb.com/story/23618230/joey-chestnut-wins-radcliff-egg-eating-contest)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAkzEusQLBw

Comment: [Eating only eggs is boring](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zw8iljkD1So).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Metabolic rate, individual genetics, cholesterol-absorption controversies, nutrients of the egg, size of the egg, and definition of "maximum" all contribute to ambiguity.
[This list of egg sizes and corresponding nutrition panels with daily recommended values is a good starting place](http://www.eggnutritioncenter.org/egg-facts/nutrition-facts-panels/), but I will also address this in a general context of what experts recommend and nutrient content.

**Cholesterol**

When people talk about eggs, they usually want to talk about cholesterol.

The problem is that the body doesn't fully absorb all of the cholesterol, so there's no hard rule. What we do know is:

- A large egg contains about 185 mg of cholesterol. [{2}](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/high-blood-cholesterol/expert-answers/cholesterol/FAQ-20058468)
- Although there is no precise basis for selecting a target level for
  dietary cholesterol intake for all individuals, the AHA recommends
  <300 mg/d on average. [{3}](http://circ.ahajournals.org/content/102/18/2284.full)
- Your body doesn't absorb everything you eat. (That's part of why we go to the bathroom.)

Registered dietitian Leslie Beck recommends:

> People at high risk for cardiovascular disease – e.g. people with diabetes, high cholesterol, and/or hypertension and smokers – should definitely limit their intake of egg yolks... some experts advise avoidance.

However, for healthy people with no medical condition, regular exercise and maintaining a healthy weight are better strategies to guard against heart disease and stroke, not cutting down on eggs (for [70](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16340654/) - [75%](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21776466) of the population). The two studies cited indicate that consumption of eggs does not raise cholesterol levels significantly for about 3/4ths of the population.

**Fat and Calories**

Each egg yolk contains 6 g of fat and 54 kcal. Even though they're full of nutrients, they still do contain calories, so factor that into your daily intake. Someone who does an average amount of physical activity would probably require an average amount of eggs. Definitely not something on the level of dozens, but even so, giving any numbers would be hard since there are so many factors in play.

**Vitamins and Minerals**

Eggs are naturally rich in vitamin B2 (riboflavin), vitamin B12, vitamin D, selenium and iodine. They also contain vitamin A and a number of other B vitamins including folate, biotin, pantothenic acid and choline, and essential minerals and trace elements, including phosphorus. [{6}](http://www.egginfo.co.uk/egg-nutrition#sthash.ueExphBh.dpuf)

Before reaching a daily recommended value of any of these nutrients though, you would probably far exceed the daily recommended values for fat and calories first, but it's possible to overdose on anything, so be sure to keep track of how much of these nutrients are in each egg that you consume in the event that you're burning off all the fat and calories.

**Summary**

To know your "maximum" number of eggs, you should probably talk to a dietitian.

**Sources**

- http://www.eggnutritioncenter.org/egg-facts/nutrition-facts-panels/
- http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/high-blood-cholesterol/expert-answers/cholesterol/FAQ-20058468
- http://circ.ahajournals.org/content/102/18/2284.full
- http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16340654/
- http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21776466
- http://www.egginfo.co.uk/egg-nutrition#sthash.ueExphBh.dpuf