# Are eggs good for heart health or bad?

Tags: heart-disease, heart

I am finding two completely contradicting posts while googling regarding health risks to the heart for excess consumption of eggs:

https://www.health.harvard.edu/heart-health/are-eggs-risky-for-heart-health

https://draxe.com/health-benefits-of-eggs/

So, are eggs good for heart health or bad? Now-a-days I am taking two eggs in my meal everyday. Had been curious to know, how safe is it?

Comment: The Harvard link is behind a paywall? If you are basing this Q on what's available in the teaser…, please say so in your question; otherwise it would be nice if you could include a bit more relevant text from that article.

Comment: Sure would be nice to be able to read that Harvard link.

Comment: With what you can see through the paywall, they both say the same thing.  (For most people, eggs do not increase your risk of a heart attack, a stroke, or any other type of cardiovascular disease.) - but as with all foods, within moderation

Comment: So now-a-days I am taking two eggs in my meal everyday. Had been curious to know, how safe is it?

Comment: Please: no discussion in comments, but update-edits to questions and then proper answers.

Comment: [How many eggs can one eat per day?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/529/43)

Comment: The egg industry has a lot of money. Bloggers are recipients of their excess. Check the references, and see if there are any disclaimers.

Comment: From the second link, a huge red flag - In 2008, he started a functional medicine center in Nashville, which grew to become one of the most renowned clinics in the world

Comment: @GrahamChiu 2nd link=Draxe? He *is* one huge red flag. Usually.

Comment: I am voting to re-open this question as it never was asking [How many eggs can one eat per day?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/529/43).  This is asking for clarification on health risks to the heart.

Comment: @Chris - While the questions are not *exact* duplicates, there is a large overlap, and the answer there substantially answers this question as well.

Comment: @Chris and the (at)MD.: This might be re-opened. If, as JohnP clarified, the overlap could be removed or at least reduced. The current suggested edit does not attempt to do this. A focus on Chris's suggestion *might* be viable.

Comment: The OP needs to address a single reason for the claimed health benefit.  These can be easily countered.